# Main javascript function in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so i started making a website, and came upon a dilemma, or maybe i didn't think that really trough:

I want my html to be able to execute a "main" obiviously i have the javascript file set up, **what should i do insthead of this, and why it is not working?**

```
<body>
<myeasytag id="easy"></myeasytag>
<script src="easy.js">main(); //i don't know if main is a keyword</script>
</body>
```

this is my easy.js

```
function main(){
document.getElementById("easy").innerHTML = "TESTFUNCTION";
}
```

Comment: You cannot combine a script tag that loads a script and calling a function at the same time

Comment: Why, i can't combine them? I know it's just another line, i just want my file to look clean.

Comment: Because only the source is loaded, but the `main-function` won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your function once the page has loaded. Try adding this to your *script* part of the page:

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", main, false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `main();` inside your main.js

it looks like this

```
function main(){
  document.getElementById("easy").innerHTML = "TESTFUNCTION";
}
main();
```

This should do the Job

Comment: Wow, i didn't even think of that, haha. But why i can't load it in the script tag?

Comment: you cant do the same thing adding script on script tag and adding src on script tag

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript function is a block of JavaScript code, that can be executed when "called" for.
For example, a function can be called when an event occurs, like when the user clicks a button.

Sample code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
}
```

```html
<h1>A Web Page</h1>
<p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Now you want to call the function on load of the page just call the function in js file.

Like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<h1>A Web Page</h1>
<p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in the web-world.

Your code looks fine - but as I mentioned  in the comments, you cannot combine an external script file with local code. Why? I don't exactly know why. But the browser won't execute your code when you also try to load a script.

Also in your HTML is a custom element which is mostly not supported yet.

So better do something like this:

easy.js:

```
function main(){
  document.getElementById("easy").innerHTML = "TESTFUNCTION";
}
```

And your HTML file should look something like this:

```
<div id="easy"></div>
<script src="easy.js"></script>
<script>
  main();
</script>
```